# make a call with iOS AppRTCDemo with resolution set to 480x640

Tags: ios, webrtc

I want to make a smooth video call between iPhone 4s with ios AppRTCDemo and nexus 4 with android AppRTCDemo.
I want a certain quality for the video, basically the higher the better but 480x640 is fine for my needs at the moment.

I have AppRTCDemo  (from r6783)  running on each of the devices (each one with the apprtcDemo for its platform).

I set the constraints for the local video :

```
RTCPair *localVideoMaxWidth = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"640"];

RTCPair *localVideoMinWidth = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth" value:@"640"];

RTCPair *localVideoMaxHeight = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"480"];

RTCPair *localVideoMinHeight = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"480"];

RTCPair *localVideoMaxFrameRate = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"30"];

RTCPair *localVideoMinFrameRate = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minFrameRate" value:@"5"];

RTCPair *localVideoGoogLeakyBucket = [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"googLeakyBucket" value:@"true"];

RTCMediaConstraints *videoSourceConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:@[localVideoMaxHeight, localVideoMaxWidth, localVideoMinHeight, localVideoMinWidth, localVideoMinFrameRate, localVideoMaxFrameRate, localVideoGoogLeakyBucket] optionalConstraints:@[]];

RTCMediaStream *localMediaStream = [self.peerConnectionFactory mediaStreamWithLabel:@"ARDAMS"];

NSString *cameraID = @"Back Camera";

NSAssert(cameraID, @"Unable to get the back camera id");

RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];

self.videoSource = [self.peerConnectionFactory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:videoSourceConstraints];
```

set same constraints in android AppRTCDemo for the local video source.

here's what happens:

start the call, then i get the local video feed

before other peer joins the call the video looks good and smooth (from the local camera).

immediately after other peer joins, then:

when call starts (both peers are in the call) i get a lot of this message:

```
Estimated available bandwidth 29 kbps is below configured min bitrate 30 kbps.
```

then:

```
Warning(webrtcvideoengine.cc:1469): webrtc: (send_side_bandwidth_estimation.cc:206): Estimated available bandwidth 29 kbps is below configured min bitrate 30 kbps.

Warning(webrtcvideoengine.cc:1469): webrtc: (send_side_bandwidth_estimation.cc:206): Estimated available bandwidth 29 kbps is below configured min bitrate 30 kbps.

Warning(webrtcvideoengine.cc:1469): webrtc: (send_side_bandwidth_estimation.cc:206): Estimated available bandwidth 29 kbps is below configured min bitrate 30 kbps.

VAdapt Frame: scaled 240 / out 1620 / in 1620 Changes: 2 Input: 480x640 i33333333 Scale: 0.5 Output: 240x320 i33333333 Changed: false

VAdapt CPU Request: keep Steps: 2 Changed: false To: 240x320

VAdapt CPU Request: down Steps: 2 Changed: false To: 240x320

VAdapt Frame: scaled 330 / out 1710 / in 1710 Changes: 2 Input: 480x640 i33333333 Scale: 0.5 Output: 240x320 i33333333 Changed: false

VAdapt CPU Request: keep Steps: 2 Changed: false To: 240x320

VAdapt Frame: scaled 420 / out 1800 / in 1800 Changes: 2 Input: 480x640 i33333333 Scale: 0.5 Output: 240x320 i33333333 Changed: false

VAdapt CPU Request: down Steps: 2 Changed: false To: 240x320
```

when i get message: `VAdapt CPU Request: keep Steps: 2 Changed: false To: 240x320`

then this message :"`Estimated available bandwidth 29 kbps is below configured min bitrate 30 kbps`" stops and the resolution is set to lower (which i guess is the intended behaviour) but i would like to keep the resolution at 640x480.

after that, there are delays in the video feed but the weird thing is that it seems the delays are coming from the the local camera view, the feed from the local camera itself is displayed with small delay, thus video is transmitted with delays to other peer and in the lower resolution.

I tried with lower resolution (320x240) and it works good when lower resolution is set, but the quality with the lower resolution is to low for me.

(i also tested with 2 android devices and there the call seems to work fine (with the resolution set to 640x480.

what can i do to get the call running smoothly with 640x480 resolution between iphone and android device?

are there maybe any other constraints i could set to get it to work properly?

i read somewhere regarding the leakybucket constraint , but it didn't help. (also , i'm not completely sure i placed the constraint in the right place)

Thanks

UPDATE:

after more testing, decreasing the maxFrameRate constraint to 15 helped with "feed from the local camera itself is displayed with small delay". with the new constraint there are almost no delays and it seems the video quality remains almost the same but the resolution is still being set to 320x240

Comment: how to compress resolution?

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of testing and having gone through a lot of threads on [discuss-webrtc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc) I realised iPhone 4s is not "strong" enough to run a smooth call with 640x480 resolution, seems to generate high cpu then decreases resolution. it evens struggles with 352x288 resolution...